# Как стилизовать selet чтобы при нажатии на него появлялась стрелка?

Tags: html, css

У меня в задании показано, что с права от select нет никакой стрелки, но после нажатия на него она появляется . Не подскажите, как это реализовать?

[image: до нажатия]

[image: после нажатия]

Comment: select:focus{ appearance: auto; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как уже написали в каментах, воспользуйтесь псевдоклассом `:focus`

наглядный пример:

```css
#abc{
width: 50px;
height: 2em;
appearance: none;
}
#abc:focus{appearance: auto;}
```

```html
<select id='abc'>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Это означает, что у вас разшириный тег `select` с возможностью выбора

```html
 <p><select size="1" name="hero">
    <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="t1">Чебурашка</option>
    <option value="t2">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="t3">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="t4">Крыса Лариса</option>
</select></p>
```

Comment: Не, это понятно. Интересует меня конкретно, как добавить стрелку после нажатия на нее. Я смог убрать ее посредством аppearance: none, но как добавить ее, когда нажимаешь на Select без понятия.

Comment: Оберните в какой-то div к примеру, потом по событию :focus добавляйте/убирайте этот триуголькик черз `:after{content:"▼"}`